# Why is the accuracy of my MLP classifier so low compared to other metrics on a multi-label text classification task?

Tags: performance, hyperparameters, multilabel-classification, mlp, sentence-transformers

I am working on a multi-label text classification task, where I want to predict the Big Five personality traits of essay writers based on their sentence embeddings. The sentence embeddings are generated by a sentence transformer model from sentence_transformers. The personality traits are `cEXT`, `cNEU`, `cAGR`, `cCON`, and `cOPN`, and they are binary labels (1 or 0). I have a dataset of 2467 essays with their corresponding labels.

I am using a MLP classifier from `sklearn.neural_network` to build and evaluate my model. I use a train-test split technique to split the data into training and testing sets, and I use various metrics such as accuracy, precision, recall, F1-score, and AUC to measure the performance of the classifier.

I want to try different parameter combinations for the MLP classifier, such as `hidden_layer_sizes`, `activation`, `solver`, `alpha`, etc., and see how they affect the performance of the model. I use a for loop to iterate over all possible combinations of these parameters, and print the evaluation metrics for each combination.

However, when I run my code, I get very low and inconsistent results for the accuracy metric. For example, the accuracy ranges from `0.05` to `0.06`, which is much lower than the other metrics that range from `0.58` to `0.60`. I also get a warning that says `Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (200) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.`

I don't understand why my model has such low accuracy. Is there something wrong with my code or my data? How can I improve my model's accuracy? What are the best parameter values for my task? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

My data looks like this:

```
           #AUTHID                                               TEXT cEXT  \
0  1997_504851.txt  Well, right now I just woke up from a mid-day ...    n   
1  1997_605191.txt  Well, here we go with the stream of consciousn...    n   
2  1997_687252.txt  An open keyboard and buttons to push. The thin...    n   
3  1997_568848.txt  I can't believe it!  It's really happening!  M...    y   
4  1997_688160.txt  Well, here I go with the good old stream of co...    y   

  cNEU cAGR cCON cOPN  
0    y    y    n    y  
1    n    y    n    n  
2    y    n    y    y  
3    n    y    y    n  
4    n    y    n    y
```

Here is the code I'm

```py
# Import necessary libraries
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Define the target matrix
Y = df.iloc[:, 2:].to_numpy()

# Convert 'y' labels to 1 and 'n' labels to 0
Y = np.where(Y == 'y', 1, 0)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(embeddings, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the parameter values to iterate over
hidden_layer_sizes_values = [(100,), (200,), (300,), (100, 100)]
activation_values = ['relu', 'tanh', 'logistic']
solver_values = ['adam', 'sgd']
alpha_values = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]

# Iterate over parameter combinations
for hidden_layer_size, activation, solver, alpha in itertools.product(hidden_layer_sizes_values, activation_values, solver_values, alpha_values):
    print(f"Running with hidden_layer_sizes={hidden_layer_size}, activation={activation}, solver={solver}, alpha={alpha}")

    # Create an instance of MLPClassifier with the current parameter combination
    mlp = MLPClassifier(
        hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer_size,
        activation=activation,
        solver=solver,
        alpha=alpha,
        max_iter=200
    )

    # Fit the classifier on the training data
    mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Predict the labels of the testing data
    y_pred = mlp.predict(X_test)

    # Evaluate the performance of the classifier using metrics
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')

    # Print the evaluation metrics for the current parameter combination
    print('Evaluation Metrics:')
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
    print('Precision:', precision)
    print('Recall:', recall)
    print('F1-score:', f1)
    print()
```